# Create 2 way custom binding with observable plugin

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

The clues for this question seem so hard to find that I begin to think it must be either obvious (and I'm missing something), useless, or impossible:

I get the 2-way binding thing in knockout with observables (ko.observables()).
However all this parenthesis are a real pain. So as I'm using Durandal, I though I'd give the `observable`plugin a try : http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Binding-Plain-Javascript-Objects.html

(for the record, I also tried this one: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/)

Both are working fine with knockout's `value`binding.

My problem is I have multiple knockout custom bindings for my application and I don't get how you update an observable property that is not a ko.observable() in these custom bindings.

In my binding I would normally do this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.testBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var myObservable = valueAccessor();
        // here I could detect if it's an observable or a POJO
        // ... how to know if it's a property ???

        $(element).blur(function() {

            // ... how to write to myObservable if it's a writable property
            // ... and not a ko.observable() ???
            myObservable($(element).val());

        });

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).val(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

However with observables, I understand I'd need the reference to the underlying object and the **name** of the property to perform an update. (I can get the former but how to get the latter?)

I've looked into the `value` binding of knockout to try to understand but without more success...

Would someone have a simple example of how it would look like with the observable plugin?
Any clue would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I don't get how you update an observable property that is not a ko.observable()" - Can you clarify this? That's pretty confusing.

Comment: With ES5 you can create properties on JS objects that have getter/setter (and thus 'are observable'). They're not ko.observable() but still have the ability to be 2-way bound without the parenthesis mess. But in a ko custom binding, I didn't get how to write to such property. (it works everywhere else except in custom bindings)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Knockout's [`preprocess` feature](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html), your binding can add a method to write to the property directly. Here's how you could do it:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.testBinding = {
    preprocess: function(value, name, addBindingCallback) {
        addBindingCallback('testBindingWriter', 'function(v){' + value + ' = v}');
        return value;
    },
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).blur(function() {
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value($(element).val());
            } else {
                allBindings.get('testBindingWriter')($(element).val());
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).val(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/U7Jeg/

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the property name you can use preprocess to store it on the binding handler like this:

```
propertyName: null,
preprocess: (value) => {
        this.propertyName = value;
        return value;
},
```

You can now access the property in your init function and combine it with bindingContext to set the value:

```
init: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) => {
        $(element).blur(() => {
            bindingContext.$data[this.propertyName] = $(element).val();
        })
}
```

Note: I'm using an arrow function above to preserve the meaning of "this." If that isn't an option for, you can do this instead:

```
init: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) => {
        thisHandler = this;
        $(element).blur(function () {
            bindingContext.$data[thisHandler.propertyName] = $(element).val();
        })
}
```