# Durandal 2.0 observable plugin with custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, observable, durandal-2.0

I have a problem with observable plugin and custom binding. Observable plugin works great with standard binding. I have created typeahead custom binding, code below. The last part of the plugin is the problem, if the value is normal observable it works. But with observable plugin it doesn't because the property is not "normal" observable. How can I set the value for selectedItem with Observable plugin?

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            valueAccessor().initialize();
            var selectedItem = allBindings.get('selectedItem');
            var minLength = allBindings.get('minLength');
            if (!minLength)
                minLength = 3;

            $(element).typeahead(
                {
                    minLength: minLength,
                    highlight: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'best-pictures',
                    displayKey: 'Name',
                    source: valueAccessor().ttAdapter(),
                    templates: {
                        ...
                    }

                }).on('typeahead:selected',
                function (event, suggestion, dataset) {
                    selectedItem(suggestion);
                });

        }
};
```

Usage

```
<input data-bind="typeahead: projectTasks, selectedItem: task"/>
```

where projectTasks is Bloodhound "datasource"

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you trying to use Knockout observables and Durandal observables with the same code?

Comment: No, I'm just using observable plugin. I first used knockout observables  and then started to convert project to durandal observable plugin. This problem was found while doing that.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789732/create-2-way-custom-binding-with-observable-plugin